# How to get Top 2 items from each category into an unstacked bar chart?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I need to create an unstacked barchart table which shows for each item category, what the top 2 bestsellers were.

```
Example Input:

item_quant | item_name | item_category
1.0        | hellokitty| toy
2.0        | mighyapple| fruit
4.0        | winnypooh | toy
2.0        | tatatu.   | toy
```

For item_category toy, the orders with the highest purchase were done by item_names: winnypooh 4.0 and tatatu 2.0.
For item_category fruit, the order with the highest purchase was done by item_names:mighyapple 2.0, there is no second entry.

Now, I want to create an unstacked barchart that plots the item_category on the x-axis and item_quant on the y-axis. However, there needs to be a breakdown by item_name. ONLY PLOT TOP 2 THOUGH!

How would I do this?

Comment: Let me know if this is what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
df.groupby(['item_category','item_name'])['item_quant'].sum().nlargest(2).unstack().plot(kind ='bar', stacked=True)
```

`groupby` item_category and item_name while calculating the sum

`.nlargest(2)` should give you the first 2 in each group

`.plot(kind ='bar', stacked=True)` specifies you want to plot a bar graph that is stacked

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But what I get is the item_quant on the x-axis and no breakdown of the other two categorical vars...can you adjust it please?

Comment: Now, it looks better in that I have the category on the y-axis and a stack breakdown by the item name. The last issue is that I to list all unique item categories (right now it is only giving me 1!). Also, I would like it unstacked.

Comment: Not sure I got you well are you saying unstacked as   df.groupby(['item_category','item_name'])['item_quant'].sum().nlargest(2).unstack().plot(kind ='bar') or try df.groupby(['item_name','item_category'])['item_quant'].sum().nlargest(2).unstack().plot(kind ='bar')